# Error 500 authentication on asp net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to implement authentication to get a token, but I have encountered a problem and my problem is that I get a 500 error when I use signingCredentials inside the tokenOption.
How do I fix the problem?

AuthController:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public async Task<IActionResult> PostLogin([FromForm] LoginVM login)
 {
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        return BadRequest();
     }
     if (!await _userRepository.IsExistsLogin(login))
     {
                return Unauthorized();
     }
     var SecretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("PWPAliakbarT"));
     var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(SecretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
     var tokenOption = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: "http://localhost:58810",
        claims: new List<Claim>
        {
           new Claim (ClaimTypes.Role,"Admin"),
           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,login.UserName),
        },
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),
        signingCredentials: signinCredentials
     );
     var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenOption);
     var user =await _userRepository.GetUserByName(login.UserName);
     object sideMe = new
     {
        RoleId="Admin",
        UserName=user.UserName,
        Email=user.Email,
        ImageAddress=user.imageAddress,
        Token=tokenString
      };      
      return Ok(sideMe);
 }
```

**Removing the code (signingCredentials: signinCredentials) fixes the error.**

StartUp.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddMvc();
   services.AddDbContext<PWPDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PWPDbContext"))
   );
   services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
   services.AddTransient<IUserInfoRepository, UserInfoRepository>();
   services.AddTransient<ISettingFRepository, SettingFRepository>();
   services.AddTransient<IRecordRepository, RecordRepository>();
   services.AddTransient<IMessageRepository, MessageRepository>();
   services.AddTransient<IExpertiseRepository, ExpertiseRepository>();
   services.AddTransient<IDocumentRepository, DocumentRepository>();
   services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
      .AddJwtBearer(option =>
      {
         option.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
         {
           ValidateIssuer = true,
           ValidateAudience = false,
           ValidateLifetime = true,
           ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
           ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:58810",
           IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("PWPAliakbarT")),
         };
       });

    services.AddCors(option =>
    {
      option.AddPolicy("EnableCors", builder =>
      {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials().Build();
      });
     });
   }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
   if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
     app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   }
   app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
   app.Run(async (context) =>
   {
     await context.Response.WriteAsync("Personal Web Site is Raning");
   });
   app.UseCors("EnableCors");
   app.UseAuthentication();
 }
```

Postman => Preview:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: IDX10603: The algorithm: 'HS256' requires the SecurityKey.KeySize to be greater than '128' bits. KeySize reported: '96'.
Parameter name: KeySize
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSignatureProvider..ctor(SecurityKey key, string algorithm)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The exception explicitly states that the security algorithm requires security key to be at least 128 bits and you passed one with only 96 bits length. `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("PWPAliakbarT")` returns byte array with length of 12 bytes, which is equal to `96` bits. So you only need to pass longer string to the method, at least `16` characters long.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was solved, I just encountered a new problem.
When I use the [Authorize] attribute in the controller and request with the postman, it gives a 404 error, while I send the token in the postman.

Comment: @Eliot Make sure that url is correct and you specify correct http verb - `GET`, `POST` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SecretKey` should be **16** character or greater than **16**.

```cs
var SecretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("16CharSecretKeys"));
//16CharSecretKeys => is 16 character
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem was solved, I just encountered a new problem.
When I use the [Authorize] attribute in the controller and request with the postman, it gives a 404 error, while I send the token in the postman.